# How to Convert Get Method To Post Method in a .bat File While i am using it under a server as cgi?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cgi

I am using cmd as cgi under apache but i did not get a good tutorial on it. Can you please explain how can i convert this script from GET method to POST method?

```
echo.
rem *** Body begins here
echo ^<html^>^<body^>
echo ^<p^>This page contains short descriptions of some batch file commands. Click each   name to view the contents.^</p^>^<dl^>
echo ^<dt^>^<a href="?CALL"^>CALL^</a^>^</dt^>
if "%QUERY_STRING%"=="CALL" echo ^<dd^>Calls one batch program from another without causing the parent batch program to stop.^</dd^>
echo ^</body^>^</html^>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are writting a Batch file to create a html one, perhaps you may be interested in [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of GET request, the information sent is located in the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable. In the case of POST requests the information sent is written in the standard input of the cgi. So, to adapt it to handle a POST you will need to retrieve the information from stdin and handle it. Something like

```
if "%REQUEST_METHOD%"=="POST" (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "^"') do (
        echo(^<div^>%%a^</div^>
    )
)
```

In this code, to handle the incoming data a `for /f` loop is used. It obtains its data using a `findstr` command that, as no file is indicated, will read data from stdin. When all the data has been retrieved by `findstr`, the `for` loop will begin processing it, line by line. In this sample, a `<div>` is generated for each line that is retrieved.

Remember that this is a batch file and the indicated code is intended to handle only textual data, and has the usual limitations of batch files: max line length is 8191 characters and all the data that the `findstr` retrieves needs to be stored in memory before starting to process it.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> echo.
> rem *** Body begins here
> echo ^<html^>^<body^>
> echo ^<p^>This page contains short descriptions of some batch file commands. Click each   name to view the contents.^</p^>^<dl^>
> echo ^<dt^>^<a href="?CALL"^>CALL^</a^>^</dt^>
> if "%QUERY_STRING%"=="CALL" echo ^<dd^>Calls one batch program from another without causing the parent batch program to stop.^</dd^>
> ```

Use `%%1` instead of `%QUERY_STRING%`.

> ```
> echo ^</body^>^</html^>
> ```

---

from what i read, the client is requesting this page like so:

`https://foo.bar.com/mywebsite/cgi-bin/myscript.bat?call`

if the client was requesting it like so:

`https://foo.bar.com/mywebsite/cgi-bin/myscript.bat?request=call`

then your code would work. almost. see, when a client requests something like so: `?call` the script is automatically receiving the `call` and storing it as an argument. in this case, `%1`.

to get it,
Use this instead:

```
echo.
rem *** Body begins here
echo ^<html^>^<body^>
echo ^<p^>This page contains short descriptions of some batch file commands. Click each   name to view the contents.^</p^>^<dl^>
echo ^<dt^>^<a href="?CALL"^>CALL^</a^>^</dt^>
if "%%1"=="CALL" echo ^<dd^>Calls one batch program from another without causing the parent batch program to stop.^</dd^>
echo ^</body^>^</html^>
```

Comment: for `?request=call` you would have to change your code to `if "%QUERY_STRING:~0,12%"=="request=call" (goto :calldef)`